# How to locate the javascript files in kentico portal engine

Tags: javascript, asp.net, kentico

I created several custom javascript files in my kentico portal. The challenge is pointing to the files from my templates.

I tried this

```
       <script src="~/CMSScripts/Custom/custom1.js" language="javascript" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

and so on for more of such. It's not working! Please, help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with:

```
 <script src="<%=ResolveClientUrl("~/CMSScripts/Custom/custom1.js")%>" language="javascript" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: @Wale you have to to do better than that. "It's not working" doesn't tell me anything. Provide the error message, snapshots, code, etc..

Comment: How do I do the same for css files?

Comment: @Wale in the exact same way... `<link href="<%=ResolveClientUrl("~/path/to/site.css")%>" type="text/css" >`

Comment: @lcarus, thanks that is very helpful. One more thing though (hope you don't call me Oliver Twist), how do I map the images src in the css to their appropriate location? I have the images in '~\App_Themes\CorporateSite\Images'. Thanks.

Comment: @Wale inside the css file, reference the images using `url`. For example: `{ background-image: url(relative/path/to/the/image.jpg }` where the `/relative/path/to/the/image` is the path from where the css file is located.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34428/discussion-between-wale-and-icarus)